# Setting up Jenkins Kuberneties plug in to work with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have an AWS EC2 running Jenkins as the master.  I have an AWS EKS Cluster setup with privateNetworking in the same VPC as the Jenkins Master for use as the pipeline.

What I am not finding is a good explanation of what Kubernetes server certificate key in the plugin is referring to.  Nor am I finding a info on how I get the credentials the plugin needs.

Doing some googling I found something that said I could do the following to get the Kubernetes server certificate key for the plugin.
`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <api server>:443 < /dev/null`
Save the cert from the result into ca.crt and then run
`base64 < ca.crt | tr -d '\n'`
That is the Cert Key the plugin is looking for.

As for the creds I have read that you can use the aws cli to create the cred but little explanation around that.  And almost no explanation of how I give the local user jenkins access to the token and how to add it to the Jenkins Secrets setup.